# How can I set a percentage width for my box that will be constant across devices?

Tags: java, android

I have become confuddled, I'm trying to set a minimum width of a box, for all devices I want it to have a minimum width of say 20% of the screen width. how can I achieve this?

I've gotten the dpWidth of two screens from a tablet and my XHDPI Galaxy S3. The S3 has a dpWidth of 300 and the tablet 800. In which case I can do this programatically by calculating 20% of the dpWidth and setting that as my boxes dp value.

I'm guessing I can't use weight because it's just for the width. So how can I do this in the XML?

Also a follow-up question, how is dp useful at all? If one device can have 300 and the other 800 then the effect of the dp changes dramatically! i don't understand why there aren't more useful units to work with, i.e the screen divided into 100 units or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use weight.  Weight in a Linear Layout is only calculated across the direction of the layout.  So if you have a horizontal LinearLayout, weight will control the relative width.  If you want the items in that layout to span the entire screen, set them all to fill_parent, set the weights accordingly (3:1 to make it 75/25%), then set the width of the parent layout to 0dp.  The result will be a fullscreen layout broken out in the weights you specified.

Dp is very useful.  1 dp is basically 1/160th of an inch.  If you want things to maintain a real world size, you use dp.  If you want it to maintain a fixed size in pixels, use px.  If you want the size to very based on font size, use sp.